# Restoring redmine issues by email and svn

Tags: backup, redmine

We lost server with redmine.
Now we have old database dump and email notifications by redmine and svn history with descriptions (descriptions contains num of issue and some comment).
Does anybody know any way to restore some of lost information?

Answer (score 0):

Well since i dont know for sure i`ve checked the manual page of redmine. Maybe you can create an repository with everything in there and than from there try to get all the datafiles to the right location on youre redmine server.
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories

It`s a pity that there is no documentation about back ups or something else.

Good luck trying to fix it!

Comment: Thanks for answer. But redmine linking to repository won't help me.

Comment: oke , i thought maybe it was a way to at least get your data back on the server.